# Segmentation fault (core dumped) after running for sometime

Tags: c, function, gcc

I am trying to print the output as

```
 func 1 ---------------1
func 2  -------2
 func 1 ---------------1
func 2  -------2
```

indefinetly.

But I am getting `segmentation fault core(dumped)` after the program executes for some time.

Why is my gcc compiler showing this error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i=2;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}

void func1(){
    printf("\n func 1 ---------------%d",i);
    i=2;
    func2();
}

void func2(){
    printf("\nfunc 2  -------%d",i);
    i=1;
    func1();
}
```

Comment: Compiler throwing seg fault? Wow...

Comment: Isnt it infinite call stack, with func1 calling func2 which in turn calls func1. How do you think it will end? BTW gcc will not throw the seg fault error, your program does.

Comment: __more importantly:__ Why did you **choose** to ignore compiler warnings?

Comment: thanks ketan mukadam for pointing that out. why is my program keeps on running

Comment: @SamuelThomson see answers below

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should declare the function prototypes prior to using them: `void func1();<newline>void func2();` (put a newline between the two declarations for readability). Your compiler should have warned you, if not compile with `-Wall`. If you are using TurboC, change school.

Comment: @SouravGhosh is there something in the standard that specifies infinite recursion to be UB/implementation defined?

Comment: @SouravGhosh why is an infinite loop (such as `for(;;) {}`) UB?

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's not that simple, I agree. It has multiple conditions, like no volatile access. I'll check the details and for time being,I'll remove my previous comment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh OK let's delete our comments dealing with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler does not throw a segmentation fault, your program does.

Your program calls `func1()` and `func2()` infinite amount of times, causing it to blow up, since the stack size will be exceeded (thus the segmentation fault will happen).

Answer (score 4):

You're calling func1 which, in turn, is calling func2, which, in turn, is calling func1 and so on. This is infinite recursion - you probably have your program printing infinitely. At some point it will run out of stack space and return the error you encountered. You need a stop condition that tells func2 not to call func1 anymore if what you intended your program to do is already done. See an example of recursion termination for a different problem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination.

Comment: @Adraian H thanks for your response. so you say that with recursion i can't get an output like that .

Comment: @SamuelThomson you _do_  get an output like that. Simply the recursion nevers ends and when the stack is full your program blows up.

Comment: It's doable with recursion, just have to pass a termination condition of sorts - say each function receives number_of_calls_to_1 and number_of_calls_to_2 parameter, first at 1, decreases the corresponding counter and checks whether it is greater than or equal to zero - if so, call the function with the new counters, else stop recursing. Try to understand that Wikipedia example well and you should be able to do it.